# Adding to local variables (integers) in Python

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a function where if the user chooses an option more than twice the output of the option will change, so when they choose the 'bench' option more than twice it will change and give them a different answer. Btw - delayedPrint() is a function I made which prints the characters one by one.

```
def menuChoice():
    notepad = 1
    delayedPrint('\n')
    choice = input('> ')
    if choice == "bench" and notepad < 2:
        moreDelayedPrint("You grab the notepad off the bench." + '\n')
        moreDelayedPrint("You flick through the pages, but don't notice anything written down." + '\n')
        notepad + 1
        optionMenu()
    elif choice == "bench" and notepad > 2:
        moreDelayedPrint("You grab the notepad off the bench." + '\n')
        moreDelayedPrint("Aha! This time you notice a small scribble near the back of the     notepad." + '\n')
        moreDelayedPrint("It reads "3472" + '\n')
        optionMenu()
```

No matter how many times I choose my 'bench' option, It reads 'you flick through the pages, but don't notice anything written down' - my 'notepad + 1' seems not to be working. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`notepad + 1`  *returns the new value*. Assign it back to `notepad` to replace the old:

```
notepad = notepad + 1
```

You'll also need to add a loop to your function; you are just asking the user once:

```
def menuChoice():
    notepad = 1
    delayedPrint('\n')
    while True:
        choice = input('> ')
        if choice == "bench" and notepad < 2:
            moreDelayedPrint("You grab the notepad off the bench." + '\n')
            moreDelayedPrint("You flick through the pages, but don't notice anything written down." + '\n')
            notepad = notepad + 1
            optionMenu()
        elif choice == "bench" and notepad >= 2:
            moreDelayedPrint("You grab the notepad off the bench." + '\n')
            moreDelayedPrint("Aha! This time you notice a small scribble near the back of the     notepad." + '\n')
            moreDelayedPrint('It reads "3472\n')
            optionMenu()
```

Now when `optionMenu()` returns the loop brings you back to the `choice` prompt.

Comment: There's likely a problem with the lifetime of the variable too, though.

Comment: More elegant is `notepad += 1` which does the same.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis: but also requires more explanation as to the different behaviour between mutable and immutable types. I adjusted my answer to the level of the questioner.

Comment: Matti, you're absolutely right. Fixed with a mixture of Martijn's answer as well as moving my 'notepad = 0' variable outside the menuChoice() function and referencing 'global notepad' inside it. Thanks for your help everyone.